# Who are the rabbanim of the story of Vehu Rachum?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, history, tachanun

The Artscroll Siddur records a tradition from the Machzor Kol Bo of three rabbanim who authored the tefillah of Vehu Rachum:

> *Machzor Kol Bo* and others record a tradition regarding the authorship of these prayers. Three elders, Rabbi Shmuel, Rabbi Binyamin, and Rabbi Yosef, were set adrift on rudderless boats by the Romans after the destruction of Jerusalem. They landed on a distant shore where they were persecuted by the local ruler. Each of the three composed a prayer requesting the ease of their plight. G-d heeded their supplications: the ruler died and was succeeded by a benevolent king who treated the three with respect and kindness.

From this story emerge a few questions:

1. Who are Rabbi Shmuel, Rabbi Binyamin, and Rabbi Yosef?
2. Why did the Romans set them adrift?
3. Where did they land?
4. Who was the king who persecuted them?
5. Who was the king who treated them with respect and kindness?

More concisely, is there a recorded history of this event (presumably not, if the Machzor Kol Bo simply records a tradition) or at least more information to be had regarding this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be at least 2 variations of this story. The Kol Bo version is actually different than the one mentioned in the question

> עובדא הוה בספינתא דיהודאי דאתא מגלותא דירושלם לאתרא דהוה תמן הגמונא אמר להון מנן עם אתון אמרו ליה מעמא דיהודאי אמר להון אם מיהודאי אתון בעינא למנסא יתכון במה דמנסא חנניה מישאל ועזריה בגו אתון נורא יקידתא אמרו ליה הב לנא זמן תלתין יומין יהב להון זמן יתבו בתעניתא וכל יומא מאן דחזו בחולמיהון הוו משתעי באפי קהלא בעו למשלם תלתין יומין הוה תמן חד סבא דדחיל חטאין ולא הוה חכים כולי האי דאמר להו חמינא בחולמאידאקרו חד פסוק דהוה כתיבא ביה תרין כי ותלאתא לא ולא ידענא מאי האי. אמר ליה חד סבא חכימא להדא האי קרא ודאי הוא דאהני לך מן שמיא כי תעבור במים אתך אני ובנהרות לא ישטפוך כי תלך במו אש לא תכוה ולהבה לא תבער בך. את ודאי תיעול בנורא ותשתזיב דהא ודאי מן שמיא אתרחיץ עבדו בטעם הגמונ׳ נורא רבתא להדא בפרשת אד׳ ועלה ההוא סבא דחלם ההוא חלמא בגו נורא ואתפליג אישתא לתלתא חלקין ואחזין ועלו בגויה תלתא צדיקים לקבולי אנפיה דההוא סבא והנהו תלת סבי בכן שבחו ואמ׳ והוא רחוםקדמאה אמ׳ עד אנא מלך רחום וחנון תנינא אמ׳ עד אין כמוך תליתאה מתמן ולהלן. ובכלהו מתחילין ברחום ומסיימים ברחום ותקונהו לאמרו בשני ובחמישי שהוא יומא דדינא.

However the Rokeach brings the story closer to the version mentioned (quoting Teshuvas Gaonim). See this link for a longer version
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3248625/jewish/Why-Is-Tachanun-Longer-on-Mondays-and-Thursdays.htm

Specifically to your questions

1. The Jews began to fast and pray to G‑d for salvation. It was then that three pious leaders of the community, two of them brothers by the names of Joseph and Benjamin, and the third a cousin named Samuel, composed these prayers
2. After the destruction of the Second Holy Temple, Vespasian placed a number of Jews on three ships with neither captains nor rudders. The ships thus began to drift helplessly. (It seems it was some sort of punishment).
3. Each ship eventually landed in a different city in France: Leiden, Orlado and Bordils. Others give the names Lyons, Arles and Bordeaux. This discrepancy is due to the fact that this story was originally written in Hebrew and is more than a millennium old.